# Oracle - Selecting full rows from GROUP BY expression

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by

I want to select full rows with use of my resulting group by. So that I can inspect rows separately. This is what I came up with but It doesn't return anything and I have no idea why.

```
SELECT * FROM myTable t ,
  ( SELECT
        prop_1, prop_2 , prop_3  
    FROM
       ( SELECT COUNT(*) AS countx,  prop_1, prop_2, prop_3 FROM myTable
         GROUP BY  prop_1, prop_2, prop_3 )  
    WHERE countx>1 )  subselect
WHERE
        t.prop_1 = subselect.prop_1
    AND t.prop_2  = subselect.prop_2
    AND t.prop_3  = subselect.prop_3 ;
```

Maybe I should try totally different approach but please explain me why this isn't working

Answer (score 1):

I need you need something like this:

```
select * from myTable where count(*) over (partition by prop_1, prop_2,prop_3) >1
```

Or if you need the duplications maybe it is cleaner this way:

```
select * from myTable t1, myTable t2 where
  t1.prop_1 = t2.prop_1 and
  t1.prop_2 = t2.prop_2 and
  t1.prop_3 = t2.prop_3 and
  t1.id <t2.id
```

Otherwise you can merge your internal 2 queries using having count(*)>1 in the most internal one, instead of the where in the second.

Comment: nice trick with partition by (I didn't know how to use it until now) but syntax was incorrect. Still after readjusting it works fine :)

Answer (score 1):

Remove the middle sub-query. Try this:

```
SELECT * FROM myTable t ,
       ( SELECT COUNT(*) AS countx,  prop_1, prop_2, prop_3 FROM myTable
         GROUP BY  prop_1, prop_2, prop_3 ) subselect
WHERE
        t.prop_1 = subselect.prop_1
    AND t.prop_2  = subselect.prop_2
    AND t.prop_3  = subselect.prop_3 ;
```

Comment: I guess it is a good answer, as well as mine approach was. It just wasn't working because i had null values and nvl solved my problem. Thanks!